# How to disable NTP client on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, ntp

I configured a Windows Server 2008 machine to be an NTP client using some instructions I found elsewhere.

```
net stop w32time
w32tm /config /syncfromflags:manual /manualpeerlist:"0.pool.ntp.org, 1.pool.ntp.org, 2.pool.ntp.org"
w32tm /config /reliable:yes
net start w32time
```

But this is actually causing more problems than it's solving. I have a couple of client-server applications that complain bitterly when the system clock changes by even a fraction of a second. So I need to undo the changes I made.

What commands do I need to enter to revert the clock sync to its default settings of not syncing with anything? Do I need to change the /syncfromflags, /manualpeerlist, and/or /reliable settings?

Answer (score 3):

to unregister the timeservice run:

```
W32tm /unregister
```

To reset it to the defaults run

```
W32tm /register
```

ou might also consider increasing the LargePhaseOffset settings so that the only time it will resync is when the time is very far off (you'll still get the app complaint but at least it will be because time really was off by alot)

See [Windows Time Service Tools and Settings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773263%28WS.10%29.aspx)